# Restore sounds for apps after Windows update (without updating drivers or reinstalling app)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio, file-association, system-sounds

Problem experienced on Windows versions 7 and 10.

Example used in this post: Quicken 99.

The problem and solution may be germane to other Windows versions and apps as well, especially if the app is old.

**Description of Problem**

After every Windows update, I lose all of the sounds associated with my Quicken 99 program. However, all non-app sounds work just fine (for example, visiting youtube, playing a CD, watching a DVD, etc.).

The Quicken 99 sound files are stored with the Quicken program folder, so missing files is not the problem. And the sound drivers are up-to-date, so that is not the problem.

What is a simple way to restore the sounds that play when I use Quicken or possibly other apps?

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please edit your original question to include the appropriate Windows [version and OS build number](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information)?  It makes a big difference regarding any proposed solutions.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Run5K - Do you mean to edit the title? The tags? Because the Windows version is already mentioned in the text. I did not mention it in the title or in the tags because I really do believe that the version is irrelevant. I had the same problem with Windows 7, had a cryptic note on fixing it that worked in the past. Today's post explains how it worked for me with Windows 10.

Comment: If you want to leave it as-is, that is entirely up to you.  That being said, I don't see anything about the Windows version within the text other than *"After every Windows update..."*  However, if this problem occured on a Windows 10 machine, it might be more appropriate to explain that within your question and add the tag accordingly.  Again, it's entirely up to you.

Comment: @Run5k - You are right; I added the version to the solution but it wasn't in the problem. I edited the text and added tags to identify Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quicken sound files are all named with this syntax: q[...].wav

When I looked in Windows>Media>Sounds, there were no q[...].wav files. So this is what I did (steps are for Windows 10; the actual folder, file names, and such may be different for other Windows versions).

1. Copy-paste the files from my Quicken folder into 
   c:\Windows\media\Quicken
2. Go to Control Panel > Sounds > Sounds tab
3. Scroll to the Quicken folder and open it.
4. Click a program event (such as Activity Bar item).
5. Select the corresponding wav file (such as qabitem.wav)
6. Test the sound of the wav file (presumably it works!).
7. Click Apply to associate the wav file with the program event.

Note: I'm aware that there are other "routes" to accomplishing these steps. This is a straightforward solution that worked for me.